# When does $(x+1)^s -x^s = x^{-s}$ have a solution?

Tags: calculus, functions, roots

Let $0\lt s \lt 1$. I want to find the range of $s$ for which the following equation has a solution for $x\ge 0$.

$$(x+1)^s -x^s = x^{-s} $$

After looking at the graphs of the LHS and RHS and Wolfram, I believe that if $s$ is greater than some unknown value, there is always one solution. For example, WolframAlpha gives no solutions for $s=0.5$ but one for $s=0.6$.

How can I obtain this transition point? Does its closed-form even exist?

I might add an idea. At that special value of $s$, the two curves must touch each other, giving the system $$(x+1)^s -x^s = x^{-s} \\ (x+1)^{s-1} -x^{s-1} = -x^{-s-1} $$
Maybe there’s a way to solve for $s$.

Comment: For the critical $s$ do they "touch" at infinity?

Comment: You can do a bisection search in Alpha manually.  I find a solution for $s=0.54$ around $x=2500$ in a spreadsheet.  Now try $0.52$ and keep going.  Someone more expert than I or having Mathematica could automate this.  For $s=0.51$ and $x$ around $2 \cdot 10^{12}$ there is a solution

Comment: @Henry That’s a point, the solution could approach $\infty$ as we get closer to the critical point.

Comment: @RossMillikan A bisection search? I’m not very good at these computational things. It’s interesting that there is a solution for $s=0.51$. I’m guessing the transition point is $0.5$.

Comment: @RossMillikan. Yes, I guess that we need to look what happens when $x\to \infty$

Comment: You would start with knowing there is no solution at $0.5$ and there is one at $0.51$.  Split the interval in half and see if there is one at $0.505$.  If there is, the transition is below that, so the interval is $(0.5,0.505)$.  Split that in half at $0.5025$ and try again.  Replace one of the endpoints based on what you find and go until you get tired or Alpha won't do it any more.

Comment: I was wrong. It is proably around $0.5+\epsilon$

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, so it’s basically hit and trial. I wish I could, but I don’t have Mathematica or any other software that can do this. WA gives up at as far as $s=0.59$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, it’s around $0.5$.

Comment: I actually did not get a solution at $0.51$.   I think that takes more precision than my spreadsheet will give.  What we need is an expansion of the left side for $s=\frac 12+\epsilon$

Comment: Have a look at the update. We have the solution. Bingo !

Comment: Have a look at my second answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I did. Nice way of actually getting solutions for $s\gt 0.5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the two functions$$f=(x+1)^s -x^s - x^{-s} $$ $$g=(x+1)^{s-1} -x^{s-1} +x^{-s-1}$$ and the norm
$$\Phi=f^2+g^2$$
My first work has been to look at the contour plot of the norm but, even if illustrative, the fact that $x$ increases more and more made the analysis not very concluding. I also tried to minimize $\Phi$ with respect to $x$ and $s$; it worked but, since $x\to \infty$, the result was depending on the working precision.

So, working with cross sections, I made $x=10^k$ and solves $\Phi=0$ for $s$. The results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & s_k \\
 0 &  1.000000 \\
 1 &  0.611256 \\
 2 &  0.562674 \\
 3 &  0.544074 \\
 4 &  0.534053 \\
 5 &  0.527757 \\
 6 &  0.523429 \\
 7 &  0.520269 \\
 8 &  0.517862 \\
 9 &  0.515966 \\
 10 &  0.514434 \\
 11 &  0.513170 \\
 12 &  0.512114 \\
 13 &  0.511181
\end{array}
\right)$$

Based on these data, I performed a least square fit for the model
$$s_k=\frac {1+a k} {1+b k}$$ which is almost perfect $(R^2 > 0.999999)$ (maximum error $=0.0002$) and the parameters are
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 a & 1.75930 & 0.00353 & \{1.75143,1.76717\} \\
 b & 3.51381 & 0.00668 & \{3.49893,3.52868\} 
\end{array}$$ predicting an asymptotic value of $0.500681$.

So, as other users concluded, there are solutions for $0.5 < s \leq 1$.

Taking this into account, a very good estimate of $s_k$ is given by
$$\color{blue}{s_k=\frac{1+k\sqrt 3}{1+2k\sqrt 3}=\frac 12 \left(1+\frac 1 {1+2k\sqrt 3}\right)}$$

Using it as a starting point for Newton method, we have very fast convergence and obtain solutions for extremely large values of $x$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k   &  s_k \\ 
 100 &  0.5014392210 \\
 200 &  0.5007206477 \\
 300 &  0.5004806627 \\
 400 &  0.5003605837 \\
 500 &  0.5002885086 \\
 600 &  0.5002404469 \\
 700 &  0.5002061115 \\
 800 &  0.5001803569 \\
 900 &  0.5001603237 \\
 1000 &  0.5001442959\\
 2000 &  0.5000721584 \\
 3000 &  0.5000481079 \\
 4000 &  0.5000360818 \\
 5000 &  0.5000288658 \\
 6000 &  0.5000240551 \\
 7000 &  0.5000206188 \\
 8000 &  0.5000180415 \\
 9000 &  0.5000160370 \\
 10000 &  0.5000144333
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If, around $s=\frac 12$, we expand $f$ and $g$ as series, we have
$$f=\left(\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)+\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \left(\sqrt{x+1} \log (x+1)-\frac{(x-1) \log
   (x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)+O\left(\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)$$ and
$$g=\left(\frac{1-x}{x^{3/2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)+\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \left(\frac{\log (x+1)}{\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac{(x+1) \log
   (x)}{x^{3/2}}\right)+O\left(\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

Solving $f=0$ for $s$ and plugging the result in $g$, we need to solve for $x$
$$\left(3 x-4 \sqrt{x+1} \sqrt{x}+1\right) \log (x)+(x+1) \log (x+1)=0$$ which does not show solution.

For large $x$, the asymptotics of the above is
$$1+\frac{\log (x)+1}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

**Update**

Without any approximation, **if** $f=g=0$, writing
$$f-x\,g =0 \implies s=\frac{\log (2(x+1))}{\log (x(x+1))}$$

Plugging $s$ in $f$ then reduces to problem to
$$1+2x=x^{\frac{2 \log (2 (x+1))}{\log (x (x+1))}}$$ which does not show solutions.

Effectively, expanding the rhs as series
$$x^{\frac{2 \log (2 (x+1))}{\log (x (x+1))}}=1+2x-\frac{\log (2)}{\log (x)}+\frac{\log (2)(\log(2)+2)-\log (x) (\log (x)+2)}{4 x \log ^2(x)}$$ and the first terms are the lhs (!!).

Then the solution is $x\to \infty$ and if this is the case
$$s=\frac 12\left(1+\frac{\log (2)}{\log (x)} \right)$$

Comment: Very useful! That approximation of $s_k$ is nice.

Comment: @Tavish. I am still working this very interesting ptoblem. Using the data for $10^{1000} \leq x \leq 10^{10000} $, the $2\sqrt 3$ is confirmed and the residues are $\leq 10^{11}$. What does $\sqrt 3$ is doing here ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Wow, I didn’t realize that $s$ could be written in terms of $x$ like that. Thank you, Claude. This completes the answer.

Comment: @Tavish. I thank you for the problem ! I had a lot of fun (at my age, it is good). Cheers :-)

Comment: @Tavish; Take care : this is valid if $f=g=0$ only

Comment: Of course. $f$ must be zero for an intersection, and $g$ should also be,no? Their derivatives should really approach the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it fails at $s=\frac 12$ but will succeed at any $s$ above that.  We have
$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x \approx \frac 12 x^{-1/2}-\frac 18x^{-3/2}$ as $x \to \infty$  The leading factor of $\frac 12$ says there will be no solution because the left side is always larger. For $x=0.52$ I found a solution around $x=1.6\cdot 10^7$ but closer than that I am running into precision errors in my spreadsheet.  I tried to get Alpha to expand the $s=0.51$ case but it wouldn't.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: That it has a solution for $s > 1/2$ ($f(0^+)=-\infty, f(x)>0$ for $x$ large) and no solution for $s\le 0$ ($f<0$) follows from $f(x)=(x+1)^s - x^s-x^{-s} = \int_0^1 (s (x+t)^{s-1}-x^{-s})dt$

Comment: @reuns Can you elaborate on that? And it is assumed that $0\lt s \lt 1$.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add another answer just dedicated to numerical aspects.*

For a given value of $s$, instead of solving for $x$
$$f(x)=(x+1)^s -x^s - x^{-s}=0$$ it looks much better to solve instead
$$\color{red}{h(x)=\log \left( (x(x+1))^s-x^{2 s}\right)=0}$$
Using what was proposed in the previous answer
$$x_0=\exp\left(\frac{\log (10)}{\sqrt{3}} \,\frac{s-1}{1-2s} \right)$$ is a good starting point for Newton method (it could probably be significantly improved).

For $s=0.52$ used by @Ross Millikan, the iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 8.47624\times 10^6 \\
 1 & 1.18276\times 10^7 \\
 2 & 1.25635\times 10^7 \\
 3 & 1.25868\times 10^7 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Still with the idea of finding a better conditionning, it is definitrly better to let $\color{red}{x=e^t}$; (his makes $f(x)$ much more linear. For the same problem as above with the same initial conditions, Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 15.952777 \\
 1 & 16.348162 
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $s=0.51$ which was making problems
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 32.570254 \\
 1 & 33.667228 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, a much better estimate
$$t_0=\frac{764}{583} \theta+\frac{6}{1015}\theta^2-\frac{1}{7097}\theta^3 \qquad \text{with} \qquad \theta=\frac{s-1}{1-2 s}
$$
For the two above examples, the estimates are $16.3333 $ and $33.5826$.